# Why are contents in the fragment are coming in my activity to which I navigate to?

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment, drawerlayout

[Please click here for the screenshots.](http://postimg.org/image/j9fopbb9x/) I have a fragment which is added to an Activity(For DrawerLayout). Now that I am trying to navigate to another activity from the fragment, the contents in the fragment(a TextView and a GridView) are also coming on the view. They are overlapping.

In the fragment i.e. HomeFragment:

```
onCreateView() {
    homeGrid.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            Intent inew = new Intent(getActivity(),
                    SubCategoriesActivity.class);
            context.startActivity(inew);
        }
    });

}
```

In the Activity

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    View contentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_sub_categories,
            null, false);
    mDrawerLayout.addView(contentView, 0);
}
```

This is my Drawerlayout

```
activity_global_home.xml
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>
<!-- The main content view -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
<!-- The navigation drawer list-->
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/drawer_list"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="#111"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/background_light"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>


and the method which adds the fragment to the drawer
private void displayView() {
Fragment fragment = null;
fragment = new HomeFragment();
break;
if (fragment != null) {
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();
}
}
```

Comment: could u please upload some more code and screen shots

Comment: @Neha Updated the screenshot in the post.

Comment: You will have to post more of your coding.

Comment: u will have to add more coding..plus i think this problem exist because u r adding layout as view to ur drawerlayout.

Comment: @JanithaR I added some more code.

Comment: you should [follow this example](https://github.com/pratyesh/Fragment-Implementation-In-Android) for fragment Implementation and Navigation in android

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do inside the `onCreate()` of the activity. Looks like you've got something's mixed up.

Comment: @JanithaR 
In the onCreate method of the Activity is such because I am extending the GlobalHome, which in turn extends ActionBarActivity

    public class SubCategoriesActivity extends GlobalHome {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this
    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View contentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_sub_categories,        null, false);
    mDrawerLayout.addView(contentView, 0);
    }

Comment: y r u not calling setContentView in ur activity...if u need the drawer to show in your next activity too then u must create another fragment and replace it instead of opening a new activity

Comment: @Neha Your suggestion helped. Thanks

Comment: But How to go to the previous fragments when I press android back?

Comment: u can create backstack.. and then pop the back stack on backpressed

Comment: u r most welcome :) Its always great to help :)